# ng serve command failed to compile in angular 7

Tags: angular7, angular-cli-v7

I have created new project with ng new and selected routing, css. It worked.

*Angular CLI: 7.1.1

Node: 10.14.1

Npm: 6.4.1*

But on ng serve/npm start command, it failed to compiled with following error.

---

```
ERROR in ./ansi-html 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> #!/bin/sh
| basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
|    
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

---

Am I missing any component/step? Please help, thanx in advance.